# How does voicemail work on android phones

Tags: android, voicemail

I have to develop a sample application to send, receive and delete voicemails on android phones, for this I need to know what mechanism is followed, in general, by other applications.

(I developed a sample using android.provider.VoicemailContract, which can insert an audio file (from SD card of phone) as voicemail. Then, my application reads and deletes the inserted voicemail with the help of android.provider.VoicemailContract.Voicemails contentprovider.)

I want to know how does voicemails work on android phone, i.e. the procedure, protocol kind of things. I googled but I did not find any relevant material. I am completely new to voicemails...I need to know all internal details.

Can anyone please describe or provide me some helpful links to understand exactly what procedure one should follow to develop such application...:/ :/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I was curious too. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744063/using-voicemailcontract-gives-permissions-error) stack overflow question and answers, applications can add voicemails to a local phone's database, but cannot read any voicemails that other apps add. Also, only the local phone application can read all the voicemails.